# How to power 3 different AC circuits without crossing them

Tags: relay, timer

I have 3 zones in my house with 3 24v thermostats. These thermostats tie into a zone relay  that triggers a 120v line to each circulator to heat that area of the house.

I need a way to have my timing circuit supply power to all 3 circulators without having the possibility of one thermostat activating all 3 zones when the timer is not on.

Is there a circuit or setup available to do this?
[image]

Comment: Are the 24 volt control lines AC or DC?

Comment: Why wouldn't you tell us what are the requrements, instead of listing the features that you don't want. It's a little difficult to understand.

Comment: AC. The power comes from my Honeywell Triple Aquastat.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I need to power all three circulators from their own individual sources and from the single timer source at different times.

Comment: Looking at Honeywell Triple Aquastat manual, there are no 24V output from it, but may I be wrong, different model. Now these Honeywell Triple Aquastat thermostats are powered with the same 24v or ther are powered with 120VAC, presumly also from different phases?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič the aquastat is powered by a 120VAC and has a single Thermostat (TT) terminal that is 24v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional layer of single pole, dual throw relays (SPDT) between the thermostats and the existing relay panel. These new relays would be wired so that they pass though the signal from the thermostats when the timer is OFF, or pass though 24V when the timer is on.

[image]

Note that the output of the timer can be anything (24 VAC, 120VAV, 5V DC...) as long as the relays are matched to it and capable of handing the 24VAC they are passing though.

Comment: This is a good idea. Thanks. Relays seem expensive though, like 30 bucks a piece. Is that about right in your experience?

Comment: Marked as the answer, but if you have a moment could you give me an example of an adequate relay circuit? I see a lot online but the prices and abilities on them are all over the place. It only needs to handle like 2 amps.

Comment: What are you using for a timer?

Comment: Wood 59402 40 amp timer.

Comment: You should be able to do it with just one of this handy [$6.19 4PDT relay](https://www.amazon.com/HH54P-Electromagnetic-Power-Relay-DYF14A/dp/B00DN34JC6/ref=as_sl_pc_ss_til?tag=joshcom-20&linkCode=w01&linkId=J5Q7NVFBVL5RO4XF&creativeASIN=B00DN34JC6) by using the 24VAC you've already got though the relay in the timer to close the relay. LMK if you can't figure out the wiring.